# Чтение после конца файла в freepascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Почему после попытки чтения после конца файла программа не останавливается и не выдает ошибку, а продолжает чтение?

```
program test2;
var
    F: text;
    S: string;
    i: integer;
begin
    assign(F, 'test2.pas');
    reset(F);
    for i := 1 to 37 do begin
        readln(F, S);
        writeln(S)
    end;
    close(F)
end.
```

Это работает даже с включенной директивой {$I+}

```
program test2;
{$I+}
var
    F: text;
    S: string;
    i: integer;
begin
    assign(F, 'test2.pas');
    reset(F);
    for i := 1 to 37 do begin
        readln(F, S);
        writeln(S)
    end;
    close(F)
end.
```

После чтения в консоли программа просто начинает выводить пустые строки.

Пишу в Linux Mint. Версия fpc - 3.0.4.

Comment: а почему вы думаете что она должна выдавать ошибку? и тем более остановиться? Ну достиг указатель конца файла, и что? Хотите читать до конца - `while not eof(f)`

Answer (score 0):

Потому что [так задумано](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readln.html).

Проверяйте if (eof(F)) или в цикле while not eof (F).

В случае с включённой проверкой ошибок ввода-вывода ({$I+}) чёткого ответа нет, по крайней мере, для линукса. С одной стороны, [вроде признавали](http://lists.freepascal.org/pipermail/fpc-pascal/2005-September/009052.html), что это баг, и говорили, что он исправлен, с другой стороны, прошло 13 лет, а встроенной обработки ситуации конца файла так и нет.

Comment: Но ведь с включенной директивой {$I+} он должен выдавать ошибку https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu38.html

Comment: @Unknown, {$I+} обрабатывает ошибки ввода-вывода. Достижение конца файла — какая ж ошибка? Если вы считаете, что _чтение_ за концом файла _должно_ давать ошибку ввода-вывода, то FPC — открытый проект, почему бы не обсудить его текущее поведение с его командой?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но во многих книгах, которые читал, написано, что после попытки чтения после достижения конца файла вызывает ошибку. Погуглил и нашел ее название: 100 Disk read error
An error occurred when reading from disk. Typically happens when you try to read past the end of a file. Взял отсюда https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html.

Comment: @Unknown вы меня заинтриговали. Ставлю fpc.

Comment: Я сам давно не программировал на Паскале. Но помню, когда на винде писал, то эта ошибка выходила. Сейчас на Линуксе заново повторяю основы, и этой ошибки почему-то нет. Если интересно, то повторяю по книге "Песни о Паскале". Кстати, не я один интересуюсь этим вопросом http://lists.freepascal.org/pipermail/fpc-pascal/2005-September/009051.html

Comment: @Unknown, я поправлю свой ответ. Спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Вдобавок по этой теме: https://www.templetons.com/brad/alice/language/language7.html , а именно: This means that you have tried to get something beyond the last element of the file. When you issue such a get, the buffer variable will become undefined and eof will become true. Should you attempt to get again, an error will occur. Еще одно подтверждение, что ошибка таки быть должна)